# Using tRPC for dynamic routes in NextJs

Tags: javascript, next.js, trpc.io

So I just started a small project using the full t3 stack (Nextjs, prisma, tailwind, tRPC), and have run into a small issue.

To give a little backstory, I have a database with artists (name, email, address, id, url) related to a "art" table (artName, artPrice, artDimensions) in pscale that I was going to pull in and make a page for based on their "url" at **pages/artists/[url].tsx**.

I set up a simple router under trpc/router/artist.ts:

```js
export const artistRouter = router({

    // Find by id
    byUrl: publicProcedure
        .input(
            z.object({
                url: z.string(),
            })
        )
        .query(async ({ input }) => {
            const { url }  = input;
            const artist = await prisma.artist.findUnique({
                where: { url },
                select: defaultArtistSelect,
            });
            if (!dealer) {
            throw new TRPCError({
                code: 'NOT_FOUND',
                message: `No artist with url '${url}'`,
            });
        }
        return artist;
    }),

}
```

For my **[url].tsx** I know I can do the below to make a call and retrieve the data for the current page based on the url. However, this does cause a small "Loading" screen to occur since it is on the client and then the data populates (also the data is undefined on first query which another thing I havent wrapped my brain around).

```js
const url = useRouter().query.url as string;
const { data: artist, isError, isLoading, isSuccess } = trpc.artist.byUrl.useQuery({ url });
```

I was hoping to SSR just the current route, but for the life of me I can not get getServerSideProps working with trpc. I could just use a prisma query to return the desired artist data, but I was trying to stick with trpc since I am doing client queries elsewhere (ie, admin views).

Is there a way to actually utilize getServerSideProps with trpc for a dynamic route?

** Update **
I completely missed the [ssg helpers](https://trpc.io/docs/v10/ssg-helpers) in the trpc docs which solved the getServerSideProps. Now it just seems really slow.

Comment: Doesn't the T3 stack advise *against* using `getServerSideProps` whenever possible? https://youtu.be/1er7Zqs_h9k

Comment: You are correct on that. It seemed like you miss out on some built in next routes like "notFound" if you didnt use getServerSideProps. Ill have to do more research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getServerSideProps()` runs on the server, so you can do anything in it that you could anywhere else on the server. This means that the simplest way to call a tRPC procedure without using SSGHelpers is by extracting the procedure logic into a function and calling that. I recorded a video about this recently: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2ZzmgShHgQ